# Problema conexao com site

Tags: php, wordpress, servidor

Eu verifiquei seu banco de dados e parece que você está excedendo nosso limite máximo de conexões_de_usuários.
Com seu plano, este limite está definido para [20] conexões max_user_connections.
Uma das razões pelas quais este limite foi atingido foi que algum código criou a conexão, mas não a fechou quando foi concluída. Como resultado, a maioria das consultas estão adormecidas, embora ainda estejam lá, então o erro é mostrado.
Para não receber este erro no futuro, eu sugeriria otimizar o script e garantir que todas as conexões sejam fechadas imediatamente após a sua conclusão.
Para isso você pode adicionar mysql_close() ao final dos scripts.
Além disso, enquanto a lista de processos em seu banco de dados não mostra o que exatamente iniciou a conexão, você pode usar o PDO (ele verificará onde a conexão é iniciada).